# Stop text with negative text-indent from going over the float element

Tags: html, css

I want to stop text going over the yellow box, and go into line below it.
I assume this happens because the indent is bigger than the first word, but is there a trick to make it entire paragraph go below the yellow line (without changing display to flex, or grid, etc. which would stop it from flowing altogether)

```css
.myfloat {
  float: left;
  width: 420px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.hanging-indent {
  text-indent: -20px; /* Negative value to indent the first line to the left */
  margin-left: 20px; /* Positive value to offset subsequent lines */
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myfloat">
</div>

<p class="hanging-indent">
    L ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget lorem nunc. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat velit vel turpis malesuada, in sodales risus tristique. Vestibulum sagittis vehicula nunc, non hendrerit odio ultrices et. Fusce consectetur eget turpis eu lobortis.    Lo ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget lorem nunc. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat velit vel turpis malesuada, in sodales risus tristique. Vestibulum sagittis vehicula nunc, non hendrerit odio ultrices et. Fusce consectetur eget turpis eu lobortis.
</p>
```

Comment: It's very unclear what result you are shooting for here. Do you want all text under the yellow box?

Comment: Yes, under, but if I had another myfloat element with `float: right`, I would like the text to float around that element, something it will not do if I change its `display` property;

Comment: You can stop items sitting next to a float by clearing, but still, it would be worth posting an image of the desire layout, as I'm still confused.

Comment: Just write in "Lorem" instead of "L" as the first word.

Comment: clear: left to `p` ?

Comment: I think the question asker wants it to look like my answer below with the `clear:both` but without actually clearing the float.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Yes, I want text to be able to wrap around, but not have first word stuck in a weird place due to negative text-indent

Comment: Right now, this seems like just a weird thing where this exact combination will not work.  A float + a negative text indent.  There's only like 2 variables here and you are saying you need them both to be where they are at right now.  I'm not sure there's a good solution here for this very specific thing unfortunately.

Comment: @ChrisBarr Yeah, I cant make text indent any other pure css way, but I will see if there are some "invisible" characters that I could use instead of whitespace to create longer strings that contain the first word and stay below the yellow box.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be ideal for whatever your needs are, but the real issue is with the float.  If you can just clear your float before the text then you are good to go.

```css
.myfloat {
  float: left;
  width: 420px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.clear { clear: both; }

.hanging-indent {
  text-indent: -20px; /* Negative value to indent the first line to the left */
  margin-left: 20px; /* Positive value to offset subsequent lines */
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="myfloat">
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<p class="hanging-indent">
    L ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget lorem nunc. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat velit vel turpis malesuada, in sodales risus tristique. Vestibulum sagittis vehicula nunc, non hendrerit odio ultrices et. Fusce consectetur eget turpis eu lobortis.    Lo ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget lorem nunc. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat velit vel turpis malesuada, in sodales risus tristique. Vestibulum sagittis vehicula nunc, non hendrerit odio ultrices et. Fusce consectetur eget turpis eu lobortis.
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using span tag for the indentation in paragraph.

```css
body {
  width: 420px;
}

.myfloat {
  width: 420px;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}

.hanging-indent {
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-indent: -20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myfloat">
</div>

<p class="hanging-indent">
    L ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget lorem nunc. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat velit vel turpis malesuada, in sodales risus tristique. Vestibulum sagittis vehicula nunc, non hendrerit odio ultrices et. Fusce consectetur eget turpis eu lobortis.    Lo ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget lorem nunc. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat velit vel turpis malesuada, in sodales risus tristique. Vestibulum sagittis vehicula nunc, non hendrerit odio ultrices et. Fusce consectetur eget turpis eu lobortis.
</p>
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you need

Comment: The indent should be negative (to the left), not positive